# How can i avoid duplication while joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join

i have **two tables**

```
  1. test 1

  2. test 2
```

---

First table has

```
**id**  -   **name**

 1      -    kerala 

 2      -    Tamilnadu
```

---

Second table

```
  **name**  -  **jid**

   value 1  -  1

   value 2  -  1

   value 3  -  1

   value 4  -  1

   value 5  -  2
```

---

**My Query --**

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM test1 t1
INNER JOIN test2 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.jid
```

---

**now i get this result**

```
**name**    -  **name**

Kerala  -  value 1

kerala  -  value 2

kerala  -  value 3

kerala  -  value 4
```

---

But i need a result like this

```
Kerala  -  value 1

        -  value 2

        -  value 3

        -  value 4
```

---

the value  ' Kerala ' should not be repeated .

Comment: What you are asking for is generally done in the layer that displays the data, not the one that generates it. Hence, you should keep the SQL you have and remove the duplicates in different layers of your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can user Group concat method.Pls check below query

```
 SELECT t1.name,GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) FROM test1 t1 INNER JOIN test2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.jid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN t2.name = t3.firstName THEN t1.name
          ELSE ''
       END AS name,   
       t2.name
FROM test1 t1
INNER JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.jid
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT jid, MIN(name) AS firstName
   FROM test2
   GROUP BY jid) AS t3 ON t2.jid = t3.jid
```

This will produce the required result as long as there is a single record having `MIN(name)` per `jid` in `test2` table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fb3a/1)

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
SELECT  IF (@oldname = name1,'',name1),
        name2,
        @oldname:=name1 AS oldname FROM
  (
    SELECT t1.name AS name1, t2.name AS name2
    FROM test1 t1
    INNER JOIN test2 t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.jid
  ) t,
  (SELECT @oldname:='' ) tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible - you can't have empty values inside returned values.